# specifying number of breaks with scales in ggplot2 without a transform?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I want my data axis to have more breaks but without a transformation on the values, how can I do it in ggplot2? eg:

```
... + scale_x_continuous(breaks=scales.trans_breaks("log2", function(x) 2^x, n=8),   limits=limits)
```

works if you want your data transformed and the `n=` parameter lets you say how many breaks. How can you specify breaks without transforming the data? Do you just give it an identity function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can give `scale_x_continuous` a vector of breaks like this :

```
n=5
breaks = seq(min(dat$x),max(dat$x), length.out = n)
m + scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks)
```

Comment: I know, but I don't want to specify the breaks values, just the number

Answer (score 28):

I prefer not to give explicit ticks based on calculations in the data, and so I want ggplot2 to pick the tick marks for me given only the limits and the number of ticks. This code works for me:

```
 library(scales)
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = trans_breaks(identity, identity, n = numticks))
```

of course you can always set the tick marks explicitly with `breaks = ...` as agstudy wrote.

Comment: Since you are not using any transformation you might as well use `pretty_breaks` instead of `trans_breaks`.